# I can't refresh my Listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I have two classes , the first one is for the GUI , where I declared my listview and the adapter , and the setters , to call them from my second class .

```
public class AndroidGUIModifier implements IMyComponentGUIModifier, IFragmentEvents {

    private transient ListView lv;
    List<String> mydeviceslist;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter ;

    public void setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> adapter) {
    this.adapter = adapter;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

    public void setMydeviceslist(List<String> mydeviceslist) {
    this.mydeviceslist = mydeviceslist;
}

@Override
public void onCreateView() {

        lv=(ListView) fragment.findViewById("xdevices") ;
        mydeviceslist  = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(fragment.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mydeviceslist);
       lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In my second class I'll wait an event to receive the list that I want to load it in my listview , then I'll call the list setter to set the new received list and the adapter setter to update it , but it didn't work , nothing was displayed despite I receieved the list of devices in my log .

```
public class triprincipal extends BCModel {
    public List<String> mydevices ;
    BCEvent bcEvent;
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =guiModifier.getAdapter();


    while (isRunning()) {
      bcEvent = waitForBCEvent();
        if (bcEvent.getID() == checkevent) {
            mydevices = bcCommandSenderPlugin.getDevicesNames(); // here I get a list of my devices
            Log.i("devices", mydevices.toString());
            guiModifier.getFragment().getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    guiModifier.setMydeviceslist(mydevices);
                    guiModifier.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            }  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **setMydeviceslist()** do it like:

```
this.mydeviceslist.addAll(mydeviceslist);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope it will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` will not work in this case, as the value of the reference you have passed to the adapter doesn't actually change.
You will need to create a new `Adapter` and set it to the `ListView` to make it work. Change your `setAdapter()` to this :

```
public void setAdapter() {
    this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(fragment.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mydeviceslist);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: I did like you said , and I added some static items to my list to test it before receiving the new list  , then when I press the button to receive the new list , my my static items disappear and it don t show the new received item.

Answer (score 0):

try to update the list in same fragment/activity and after update call notifyDataSetChanged() both in same activity/fragment ....donot set adapter on list repetedly......hope it helps